# dynamic Autofill/FillDown but the start range is unknown

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to build a VBA code where I have formulas in the last row of a worksheet from columns B to H, the last row of the worksheet changes each time and the Formulas need to be filled from B to H to row 40, Ie. the end of the range is H40.

How can I make the code dynamic to pick the correct cell in column B to Autofill formulas?

```
    'Calculate Last Row in the Report
    Sheets("Result").Select
    LastRow = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    'Select and Drag Formula
    Range("B1").End(xlDown).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Range(Cells(LastRow, 2) & ":H40"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I also tried an alternate method where I would mention the start and end range to make it easier for VBA to pick the range limits.

```
    Dim EndCell As Range
    Dim FillRange As Range
    
    Set the end cell of the range
    Set EndCell = Range("H40")
    
    'Define the range to autofill
    Set FillRange = Range(Cells(LastRow, 2), EndCell)
    
    'Autofill the range
    FillRange.AutoFill Destination:=FillRange.Resize(, 10), Type:=xlFillDefault
    'Set FillRange = Range("B" & LastRow & ":H40")
    'FillRange.AutoFill Destination:=FillRange, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Lets say the last row in the report, which has formulas is row 9, then the formula would be desired to be

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B9:H40"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

How can I make the code dynamic to pick the cell in column B to Autofill formulas?

The error given by the code is "`AutoFill method of Range class failed`".

Comment: Is there initially something below the last row, the row containing the formulas? Will the last column, column `H`, ever change?

Comment: There is nothing below the last row, the row containing the formulas. The column H would never change.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Down Formulas

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDownFormulas()

    Const WS_NAME As String = "Result"
    Const WS_COLUMNS As String = "B:H"
    Const LAST_ROW As Long = 40

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = ws.Columns(WS_COLUMNS) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim FirstRow As Long: FirstRow = lCell.Row
    If FirstRow >= LAST_ROW Then Exit Sub ' filled already
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With ws.Rows(FirstRow).Columns(WS_COLUMNS)
        Set rg = .Resize(LAST_ROW - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    rg.Formula = rg.Rows(1).Formula
 
End Sub
```